# Can "aujourd'hui" ever be used as a noun?

Tags: noms, contractions

"Today is monday".

I've learned you cannot say "Aujourd'hui est lundi". Instead, you must use "Aujourd'hui, c'est lundi".

But what about other tenses?

"Today has been a weird day", for instance. Google Translate (not perfect, I know) shows "Aujourd'hui a été un bizarre jour". Should it be "Aujourd'hui, ça a été un bizarre jour"? (Maybe with a contraction?)

Comment: The reason you're confused is not because *aujourd'hui* can't be used as a noun. It's that French grammar often turns *is* into *c'est*: *L'état, c'est moi. (I am the state.) Vouloir, c'est pouvoir. (To want to is to be able to.).* I'd make this an answer, but I don't really understand when you have to use *c'est*. Maybe somebody else could add an answer explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Can “aujourd'hui” ever be used as a noun?

Sure, any word can be used as a noun.

> ***Aujourd'hui** est un mot qui doit être à la vérité considéré comme composé lorsqu'il s'agit d'étymologie, mais que la grammaire ne veut et ne peut, dans l'usage ordinaire, considérer que comme un seul mot, sans nul égard pour les éléments qui le composent.* L. Platt, *Dictionnaire critique et raisonné du langage vicieux ou réputé vicieux*, 1835.

Moreover, while it is true *aujourd'hui est lundi* is not idiomatic, there are certainly some cases, more literary than casual, where *aujourd'hui* can be a real noun like:

> ***Aujourd'hui** n'est pas un jour comme les autres.* Louis Aragon, *Les communistes*, 1966
>
> *Tu dis qu'il ne faut pas que j'écrive longuement ; mais **aujourd'hui** est jour de fête ; le silence insolite de ma rue le signifie.*  Mireille Sorgue, *Lettres à l'amant*, 1985.

- But what about other tenses?

The sentence "Today has been a weird day" might be translated to:

> ***Aujourd'hui** fut une étrange journée*.

In more conventional French, that might be:

> *Ça a été une journée bizarre **aujourd'hui**.*
>
> ***Aujourd'hui**, ça a été une drôle de journée.*

Comment: « Un aujourd'hui de douze ans, cela permet bien des jours de vingt-quatre heures, et un temps ponctué d'hiers, d'aujourd'huis et de demains. » (Alain Rey à propos des *Contemplations*, [plus](https://www.nouveau-magazine-litteraire.com/peut-dire-%C2%ABau-jour-daujourdhui%C2%BB).

Answer (score -1):

1.For other tenses you add an indefinite article or a specification, of which there are many.

- Ce jour-là était *un* lundi.
- Ce jour dans deux semaines sera *un* lundi.
- Ce jour-là a toujours été un lundi et on l'appelle le lundi de Pâques.
- C'était *un* lundi, un jour bizarre.

- C'était lundi *dernier*, un jour bizarre.
- C'était lundi *il y a [deux semaines/trois semaines/…]*, un jour bizarre.
- (*literary language*) Ce fut *un* lundi bizarre.
- Ce sera lundi *prochain*, un jour bizarre. (*It is difficult to say that the day will be strange here; it can't be strange in any other way than because of  certain coincidences as foreseen by the speaker to occur on that particular day.*)
- Ce sera *un* lundi, un jour bizarre puisque c'est le lundi de Pâques.

2.Yes, you can say that, except you must reverse the order "adjective/noun".

- Aujourd'hui a été un jour  bizarre.

  However, it is not often used ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Aujourd%27hui+a+%C3%A9t%C3%A9+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAujourd%27hui%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20un%3B%2Cc0)) and you say more idiomatically this ([ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=La+journ%C3%A9e+a+%C3%A9t%C3%A9+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20bonne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20tr%C3%A8s%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20longue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20chaude%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20belle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20rude%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20calme%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20dure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20assez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20marqu%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2CLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20bonne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20tr%C3%A8s%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20longue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20chaude%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20belle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20rude%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20calme%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20dure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20assez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20journ%C3%A9e%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20marqu%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)).
- La journée a été bizarre aujourd'hui.

Comment: Thanks. I found the second item specially useful. I know I've seen that way of constructing sentences in some places. I wouldn't know about the first item, though. Does some care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: @JDGamboa I don't see anything wrong with the first item, bar that there is more to be said; I'll try an addition now.